# Allowed memory size of X-bytes exhausted

Tags: php, memory

I have a code which upload images in folder with a unique name.I am using this line of code to generate an unique name `$uniquename=uniqid(rand()).time();`.
It gives me an error

> Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 7380 bytes)

I have read post regarding this  but they say *i should increase my memory in localhost or i should fix the bug*.

For the time being i don't want to increase the memory.How could i manipulate my unique name such that it doesn't ever pops up that error.I am using this method on an eCommerce website where user upload images but the things is i want this imagename to be unique for every user.

**Note:**

- User can upload as many images he wants.
- A simple line of code,not present inside any loops

**Full code:** http://codepad.org/emf1jKFr

Comment: Does the code appear inside a loop? Can you show a larger portion of it?

Comment: Nope this is not inside any kind of loop it is just a simple line of code @toomanyredirects

Comment: That particular function call is not the problem. It's just the drop that causes the bucket to overflow, so to speak. You're simply using too much memory doing whatever you're doing **before that**.

Comment: Did add memory size of php working thread is acceptable to you? 
you can add ini_set('Memory_limit', '256M') in your php script and that only change memory limit to 256 mega bytes in that script's session, its not a global setting

Comment: sprinkle your code with echoes of `memory_get_usage()` (or `(memory_get_usage()/1048576)." MiB"`)

Comment: @KevinYan I can give it a try.

Comment: FYI, `mt_rand()` is approximately four times faster than `rand()`

Comment: Please post the full code.

Comment: @CharlotteDunois check the updated question